# User friendly Postgres data input front end options?

Tags: database, postgresql, libreoffice-base

I'm working on a native app which uses a PostgreSQL database which I currently update and maintain. The project needs to be updated by non-computer savvy people in the future however so I need to create a user-friendly front end, for untrained staff to run simple CRUD operations on, without breaking the app (by say inputting an incorrect date-time format or swapping the x,y coordinates for locations, etc.).

I currently use PgAdmin on my side, though it's quite unfriendly to someone with little database knowledge so I'm looking for a very bare-bones data input software. I've looked into Libre office base (they have a neat form option), though it's not as customizeable as I'd like (i.e. allowing the user to type in regular days of the week in the form and having it write JSON to the db), and not too many string restrictions (i.e. must have no spaces, etc.).

If anyone has any recommendations, that would be a huge help! Thank you :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be best to just create your own interface tailored to your specific needs?

Comment: @404 Thing is I'm familiar enough with databases and have a working proficiency in javascript, though the task seems pretty daunting and I don't really know where I would start with that... if you have any pointers and you don't think it'll be too time consuming I'm all ears though!

Comment: I can't really give useful suggestions as what works for me probably won't work for you. Personally since I know c# I'd write a simple winforms or WPF application, using npgsql behind it to interact with the database. I've done this a number of times and it's simple - provided you know how already. But of course if you're not familiar with those then that's not much help.

Comment: That's fair... I'm looking into a JS/HTML option for a simple form now. thank you for the reply though!